# Replacing id with name form another table in existing query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

here's my query for getting the remaining stocks of each `Product_Id`. However, I'm not sure how to go about adding `Product_Name` from `Product` table. I just want to replace the `i.Product_Id` with `p.Product_Name` with p being the alias of Product. I know that the `Product p` should be inserted in the `FROM` but not sure how to connect it with the given query.

By the way, `Product.Id = Inventory.Product_Id`

```
SELECT 
i.Product_Id,
i.Stocks,
s.Sales,
i.Stocks - s.Sales AS Remaining
FROM (SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS Stocks FROM inventory GROUP BY product_id) i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS Sales FROM sales_detail GROUP BY product_id ) s
USING(product_id);
```

Thanks in advance guys!

UPDATE!!
The query below is my updated one, can someone check if I linked the product correctly with the existing `JOIN USING`, thanks!

```
SELECT 
i.Product_Id,
p.Product_Name,
i.Stocks,
s.Sales,
i.Stocks - s.Sales AS Remaining
FROM (SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS Stocks FROM inventory GROUP BY product_id) i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS Sales FROM sales_detail GROUP BY product_id ) s
USING(product_id)
JOIN Product p
ON i.Product_Id=p.Id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `JOIN` with the `Products` table.

```
SELECT 
    p.Product_Name,
    i.Stocks,
    s.Sales,
    i.Stocks - s.Sales AS Remaining
FROM (SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS Stocks FROM inventory GROUP BY product_id) i
JOIN Products AS p USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS Sales FROM sales_detail GROUP BY product_id ) s
USING(product_id)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I also answered my question while waiting for answers. Is the query at the bottom of my updated question correct too? Would it really be better to use your LEFT JOIN instead of a normal JOIN?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm still reviewing your query. Why did you put the `JOIN` of Products table between the `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN`? Would it have a different result if you just put the `JOIN` of Products right after the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: It may not make a difference in this case, but in some cases it's important to have all the inner joins before the outer joins.